# how to add timer in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am doing a game that will count number of clicks then add scores. What i want is to add a timer, for example: the timer is 10 secs and the click done is 25 and your score is 35 points if the timer stopped the button(the one used to count the num of clicks) cannot be clicked and it will pause for a while, plan to make a little animation before it moves to another frame.

Want to make this simple as possible since design is more important than the codes, because it is a design base class.

Please no hitTestObject or classes, and i want to avoid arrays too :( last time a used them is a disaster...

Sorry for being noob
And thank you for advance

Here is the cODE:

```
 var power:Number = 0;
    var myTimer : Timer = new Timer(10 * 1000, 0);


    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function( e:TimerEvent ):void    
    {
        myTimer.start();
        trace("time up");
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("hit");
        if (power == 5)
        {
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("mini");
        }
        else if (power == 15)
        {
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("mini");
        }
        else if (power == 25){
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("belowAve");
        }
        else if (power == 35){
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("ave");
        }
        else if (power == 50){
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("ave");
        }
        else if (power == 65){
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("highAve");
        }
        else if (power == 80){
        bgBack.gotoAndPlay("magni");
        }

});

pressBtn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, function( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
   power++;

     if (power == 5)
    {
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("one");
    }
    else if (power == 15)
    {
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("two");
    }
    else if (power == 25){
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("three");
    }
    else if (power == 35){
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("four");
    }
    else if (power == 50){
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("five");
    }
    else if (power == 65){
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("six");
    }
    else if (power == 80){
    gauge.gotoAndPlay("seven");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTimer : Timer = new Timer( 10 * 1000, 0 );
myTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function( e:TimerEvent ):void
{
    //here the timer ends and you can do stuff with the clicks.
    //the ,0 means it will repeat this over and over and over. 10 seconds * 1000 milliseconds because its kept in milliseconds.
});
myTimer.start();
```

and also

```
var myClicks : Number = 0;
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, function( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    myClicks++;
});
```

Comment: i done your code but i got an error: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 3 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before end of program. if i put the timer at the top the //error change from before end of program to before pressBtn?

Comment: @BlueDragon I fixed Discipol's post, after it is Peer reviewed it will show.  What I did was add ');' after all the '}'s

Comment: timer not working, nothing happens is there something wrong with my codes, btw i add the ")".

Comment: add myTimer.start() after the listener is added.

Comment: where exactly should i put the timer look at my code i update it? i tried to put inside the {}, before 'myTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function( e:TimerEvent ):void' and after of it but nothing work among them

Comment: I edited my post. put a trace( "clicks: " + myClicks ) inside the event listener for the timer.

Comment: tried it and still not working is there something that i need to add in the top of the codes just like in c++ and c#?

Comment: what IDE are you using? I will make a complete project for you when I get home from work.